# Phone as Bluetooth card for the computer

Tags: android, bluetooth, usb

How can I use my Android phone like a Bluetooth card for my computer?

I plan to give my computer the ability to connect with my Bluetooth headset using the mobile phones Bluetooth capability. Is there anyway to use my phone as "Bluetooth card" for my computer?

Could it be possible with an USB connection?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly, no. At the very least you would need an app on the phone to act as a bridge to send and receive data to the bluetooth device.  You might also need a driver or application to make use of the data on the pc.

In any case, this would not be very practical as there would be quite a bit of lag between the pc and Bluetooth device because of the data translation.

At the current prices for micro sized bluetooth USB dangles, you would be better off. You can find them as low as 10 bucks these days.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it seems like this isn't so simple as USB tethering is. However, is it possible then to forward the sound output of Windows to my Android phone? If so I could simply connect my Bluetooth headset to my Android phone then.

Comment: Not that I am aware of, no. There might be an app that does it, but I haven't seen one. The problem is that Windows only sees the phone as a storage device and not as a streaming device like a headset. When using USB tethering, Windows can use the phone as a modem for a network connection. Maybe with some rooting and a specialty app it MIGHT be possible, but it's not very likely.

Comment: Nevermind. I tryed it out with SoundWire, it streamed the sound to my Android device but the latency was horrible.

Comment: You might be able to improve the quality if you set up QoS on your router to give priority to the MAC address of your phone.