# Use mobile like Bluetooth dongle for pc

Tags: android, windows, bluetooth

### Can I Use A Mobile Phone As Bluetooth Dongle For Pc

I am searching through the web for quite a while now and I couldn't find a better solution/workaround for this. I found [this article](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-use-a-phone-as-a-bluetooth-dongle)

but I am stuck at *step 3*

Can anyone have the answer to it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Not directly, no.**

Please check duplicate question: [Phone as Bluetooth card for the computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27467457/phone-as-bluetooth-card-for-the-computer)

Comment: ok, that means there is no way I can connect mobile like that? to the pc